# Knockout binding for array is not recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am having an issue with my knockout not being recognized in html:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="control-group">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Rates</legend>
                <div id="creditcards-rates" class="row-fluid">
                    <p data-bind="visible: rates() == undefined || rates().length == 0">
                        No rates added yet.
                    </p>
                    <table data-bind="visible: rates() !== undefined && rates().length > 0" class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Payment Status</th>
                                <th>Income Amount</th>
                                <th>Confirmed by Provider</th>
                                <th>Payment Status</th>
                                <th>Notes</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: rates">
                        <tr>

                            <td>
                                <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: Id, attr: { id: 'Rates[' + $index() + '].Id', name: 'Rates[' + $index() + '].Id' }" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a id="btn-remove" data-bind="click: $root.removeRate"><i class="icon icon-minus"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <button class="btn" data-bind="click: addNewRate"><i class="icon icon-plus"></i> Add New Payment</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem is where data-bind doesn't recognize the values. I get error in console:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[data-bind='value:
>   Id, attr: { id: 'Rates[' + $index() + '].Id', name: 'Rates[' +
>   $index() + '].Id' }']
>
> ...);return a},bc.error=function(a){throw new Error("Syntax error,
>   unrecognized exp...

My knockout is:

```
var Micki = Micki || {};

Micki.Electro = {

    Edit: function (options) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            id: 0
        }, options);

        var _alerts;
        var _rates;
        var vm;

        function init(alerts, rates) {

            _alerts = alerts;
            _rates = rates;
            vm = new ViewModel();
            ko.applyBindings(vm);

            function ViewModel(options) {
                var self = this;

                self.mediator = null;
                self.publishKey = options.publishKey;
                self.rates = ko.observableArray([]);

                self.init = function (mediator, alerts, rates) {
                    self.mediator = mediator;
                    self.alerts = alerts;

                    //Rates.
                    $.each(rates, function (index, rate) {

                        var _rate = {
                            Id: ko.observable(rate.Id),
                            PaymentType: ko.observable(rate.PaymentType),
                            IncomeAmount: ko.observable(rate.IncomeAmount),
                            ConfirmedDate: ko.observable(rate.ConfirmedDate),
                            PaymentStatus: ko.observable(rate.PaymentStatus),
                            Note: ko.observable(rate.Note)
                        };

                        self.rates.push(_rate);
                    });

                    self.container.on("change keypress paste focus textInput input", function () {
                        self.mediator.publish(self.publishKey);
                    });
                };

                self.initFields = function () {
                    self.fields = [];
                    _.each($("[name^='Rates']"), function (field) {
                        self.fields.push(new Crate.Core.Field($(field), self.mediator, self.publishKey));
                    });

                    //_ratesAndTiers.initFields();
                    //_campaignSpecific.initFields();
                };

                self.addNewRate = function (data, event) {
                    alert("test");
                };

                return self;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a **runnable** [mcve] via Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button)? That will help you get quality answers more quickly.

Comment: In and of itself, that expression is fine: https://jsfiddle.net/uv4tr7t8/

Comment: I second T.J. here. While it's laudable that you provide your code (surprisingly many people don't), you provide way more than necessary. Most of your code is not related to your issue. Only one HTML element would be necessary and your JS could probably be trimmed to 1/4 the size to demonstrate your problem. It would be useful for the people reading your question to keep it short (it saves them time) and for yourself (you get to understand your issue much better when you reproduce it in a stand-alone example).

Comment: That being said, my first observation is that your `init()` function is never called - and it's entirely uncallable, as it sits inside the scope of your `Edit()` function that never returns any value. So this can't be right.